# Operating System configuration parameters in ERP-CRM systems?

Tags: operating-system, crm, erp

I'm searching for information about "**Operating System configuration parameters** in ERP, CRM systems: definition, types and use".

I can't figure out what these configuration parameters are, since I have searched in Spanish and English and I cannot find anything.

The only thing I could find was about:

- Server connection
- DB access
- Language configuration
- Country localization files

I've nothing to contrast this info, so I would appreciate if someone tells me what this term refers to, because these items don't seem like Operating System parameters to me. When I think about Operating System parameters, I think in *PATH* and similar stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though in general terms [Operating System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) means

> An operating system (OS) is system software that manages computer hardware and software resources and provides common services for computer programs. The operating system is a component of the system software in a computer system. Application programs usually require an operating system to function.

The actual definition in your context mostly refer to the [Operating Environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_environment)

> In computer software, an operating environment or integrated applications environment is the environment in which users run application software. The environment consists of a user interface provided by an applications manager and usually an application programming interface (API) to the applications manager.
>
> An operating environment is usually not a full operating system but is
>   a form of middle-ware that rests between the OS and the application.

This is the reason you found the answers relating to

- Server connection
- DB access
- Language configuration
- Country localization files
- Database Server
- Server OS

and similar topics as that actually is the Operating environment in context of applications like CRM,ERP etc.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's too late to be useful, but thank you anyway for your answer.